# Read a property from form serialize in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a form serialize before doing form submit like this  on click event of a button

```
 $(document).on('click', '.btnSaveNewField', function(){ 
         var $form = $(this).parent().closest(".create-fieldForm");
        console.log($form.serialize());
```

And i am getting the response similar to this

```
 Category=Profile&ApplicationFormId=7&FieldName=sd+sd+&IsCheck=false...
```

And how can i read 2 property from this i want

```
 var category="";
var  applicationformId="";
```

Comment: `var category = $form.find('[name="Category"]').val()`....